# Index was outside the bounds of the array in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

vs give that error on this line "lbl10_drink.Text = reader[1].ToString();" 
my connections work correct and The values correctly observes for connection string and the readers[0]...... also my querys work correctly . whats the problem?

```
 {

    using (SqlConnection connection1 = DBConnection.getConnection())
    {
        string strquery1 = " with distinctvalueyes (typearticle) as (select top 1 'Fruit' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Fruit=1  union all select top 1 'Drink' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Drink=1 union all select top 1 'Desert' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Desert=1  union all select top 1 'MainFood' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where MainFood=1 union all select top 1 'Salad' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Salad=1 union all select top 1 'TableFlower' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where TableFlower=1 union all  select top 1 'SaloonLighting' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where SaloonLighting=1 union all  select top 1 'Saloondesign' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Saloondesign=1 union all select top 1 'SloonCrew' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where SloonCrew=1  union all  select top 1 'Pastry' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Pastry=1 union all  select top 1 'GiftCard' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where GiftCard=1 )  select * from distinctvalueyes ";
        connection1.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1.Connection = connection1;
        cmd1.CommandText = strquery1;
        string cis = Session["customerID"].ToString();
        lbl2_customerid.Text = cis;

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            lbl8_fruit.Text = reader[0].ToString();
            lbl10_drink.Text = reader[1].ToString();
            lbl11_desert.Text = reader[2].ToString();
            lbl12_mainfood.Text = reader[3].ToString();
            lbl13_salad.Text = reader[4].ToString();
            lbl14_tableflower.Text = reader[5].ToString();
            lbl15_saloonlighting.Text = reader[6].ToString();
            lbl16_saloondesign.Text = reader[7].ToString();
            lbl17_salooncrew.Text = reader[8].ToString();
            lbl18_pastry.Text = reader[9].ToString();
            lbl19_giftcard.Text = reader[10].ToString();


            using (SqlConnection connection2 = DBConnection.getConnection())
            {
                //query for fetch service prices 
                string strquery2 = "SELECT Fruit_price,Drink_price,Desert_price,MainFood_price,Salad_price,TableFlower_price,SaloonLighting_price,SaloonDesign_price,SaloonCrew_price,Pastry_price,GiftCard_price  FROM GenReservationServicePrice";
                connection2.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd2.Connection = connection2;
                cmd2.CommandText = strquery2;
                SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader2.Read())
                {
                    string Fruit_price;
                    string Drink_price;
                    string Desert_price;
                    string MainFood_price;
                    string Salad_price;
                    string TableFlower_price;
                    string SaloonLighting_price;
                    string SaloonDesign_price;
                    string SaloonCrew_price;
                    string Pastry_price;
                    string GiftCard_price;


                    Fruit_price = reader[0].ToString();
                    Drink_price = reader[1].ToString();
                    Desert_price = reader[2].ToString();
                    MainFood_price = reader[3].ToString();
                    Salad_price = reader[4].ToString();
                    TableFlower_price = reader[5].ToString();
                    SaloonLighting_price = reader[6].ToString();
                    SaloonDesign_price = reader[7].ToString();
                    SaloonCrew_price = reader[8].ToString();
                    Pastry_price = reader[9].ToString();
                    GiftCard_price = reader[10].ToString();


                    lbl8_fruit.Text = Fruit_price;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first query you are return only one column, so when it reaches the index [1] which is second column it is out of bound of the array

You have only one column because you are using a UNION ALL which is only stacking data on top of each other

If you dont want to change your c# code you could write your query like that

```
SELECT 
    (select top 1 'Fruit' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Fruit=1) as fruit,
    (select top 1 'Desert' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Desert=1) as desert,
```

It is ugly but it would work. Of course repeat that for all your options MainFood, Salad etc...

Comment: so , in first query i want fetch only true values from sqlserver , maybe more than one value is true , now what should i do?

Comment: sorry but your query was not work , i test that in management studio and it has more errors

Comment: You dit not specify the tables schema, neither the dataset so it is quite difficult to help. I encourage you study at least a little bit the answer (more than 2min)